# HtmlAgilityPack FileLoadException when targeting NETStandard and Full Framework

Tags: c#, manifest, html-agility-pack, filenotfoundexception, .net-standard

I'm running into a problem with referencing Nuget packages in a NETStandard Library (v2.0) and a project targeting the full framework (v4.7). The full framework project (A) references the NETStandard library (B). The NETStandard library references the HtmlAgilityPack Nuget package (C).
I already fixed a part of it because the Nuget packages are not copied into A's binaries folder.
Putting

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
</PropertyGroup>
```

already fixed this.
Now I get a `System.IO.FileLoadException` with the exception message:

```
"HtmlAgilityPack, Version=1.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference
```

Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the net47 project a console/windows application or a library (library, unit test, web application)?

Comment: The net47 (A) is a console application.

Comment: No one else running into this problem? I'm doing nothing else than creating a complete new netstandard project, installing nuget package HtmlAgilityPack, creating a full framework console application and referencing the netstandard project. Executing crashes with PublicKeyToken=null Exception.

Comment: Is the NuGet package installed into the full framework application? if it doesn't use `PackageReference` (`packages.config` or classic project), it doesn't get transitive references..

Comment: Yes, the package is copied into the full frameworks application binary path. I think the problem is, that there is a missmatch in the HtmlAgilityPack.dll When I download the nugetpackage there is one for net45 and one for netstandard2.0 I have uploaded a simple project here: 
[Sample Solution](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtNCXWMgqkNoahB3t6o6o9jphVg)